# PostgreSQL unique string field

Tags: java, postgresql

My database is PostgreSQL. The language is Java.
Table name is `phrase` with column name `name`.

At any time many users are inserting many rows to this table.
And we need to make sure that a certain field is unique.
And if such a field was found during loading, I want to return the row ID.

I could for example make a field the unique primary key, and when a row id inserted, catch the exception and look up the existing row.
But I think that is a bad idea.

I could just look for that row first and then insert.
But how can we avoid that the concurrent transactions get in each other's way?

And when downloading, is it better to do a batch download, and how do I do that in PostgreSQL? I do not even know.

Comment: can use transactions level?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `UNIQUE` constraint and `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, name)
   VALUES (1, 'me');
```

Now to run a batch `INSERT` that returns the `id` of each affecte row, run

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name)
   VALUES (2, 'me'),
          (3, 'new')
ON CONFLICT (name)
   DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name
RETURNING id;
```

The strange `UPDATE` that does not actually change the row is necessary if you want the `id` back.

Comment: Will can i use instead string value use string hash code for search? it will speed search?

Comment: What is a string hash value?

Comment: I think the question is: how performant is this sort of unique constraint and if it's not, can we hash the string first and then constrain on the hash being unique instead of the string itself.
Though the database implementation could do this under the hood anyway.

Comment: Using a hash would be slower, because the hash has to be calculated. Besides, there is always the chance of a hash collision, so using a hash in a unique condition is questionable. Only consider such ideas if the strings are really long.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching the exception, you can use the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause available in PostgreSQL. By checking the number of affected rows (returncode of `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate`), you can detect if there was a conflict.

E.g.

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into x values (?,?) on conflict do nothing");
 pstmt.setInt(1, myId);
 pstmt.setInt(2, myValue);
 int rc = pstmt.executeUpdate();
 if (rc == 0) {
    // fetch the existing row...
 }
```

Comment: Will can i use instead string value use string hash code for search? it will speed search?

Comment: just use the string; since you need a unique index anyway, it will be fast enough